# Windows batch file - splitting a string to set variables

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, delimiter

I feel like I'm going around in circles with FOR loop options.

I'm trying to take a string (output of a command) and split it on commas, then use each value to SET, e.g.

String: `USER=Andy,IP=1.2.3.4,HOSTNAME=foobar,PORT=1234`

So I want to split on comma and then literally use that variable in SET.  I don't know ahead of time how many many variables there will be.

I've tried things like:

```
FOR %%L IN (%MYSTRING%) DO ECHO %%L
```

but that splits on the equals sign too so I end up with

```
USER
Andy
IP
1.2.3.4
```

etc

I just want to be able to do the following so I can `SET USER=Andy` etc, something like:

```
FOR %%L IN (%MYSTRING%) DO SET %%L
```

What option or flags am I missing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The default delimiters for elements in plain `FOR` command (no `/F` option) are spaces, tab, commas, semicolons and equal signs, and there is no way to modify that, so you may use `FOR /F` command to solve this problem this way:

```dos
@echo off 

set MYSTRING=USER=Andy,IP=1.2.3.4,HOSTNAME=foobar,PORT=1234

:nextVar
   for /F "tokens=1* delims=," %%a in ("%MYSTRING%") do (
      set %%a
      set MYSTRING=%%b
   )
if defined MYSTRING goto nextVar
echo USER=%USER%, IP=%IP%, HOSTNAME=%HOSTNAME%, PORT=%PORT%
```

Another way to solve this problem is first taking the variable name and then executing the assignment for each pair of values in a regular FOR command:

```dos
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set MYSTRING=USER=Andy,IP=1.2.3.4,HOSTNAME=foobar,PORT=1234

set varName=
for %%a in (%MYSTRING%) do (
   if not defined varName (
      set varName=%%a
   ) else (
      set !varName!=%%a
      set varName=
   )
)
echo USER=%USER%, IP=%IP%, HOSTNAME=%HOSTNAME%, PORT=%PORT%
```

**EDIT 2023/01/20:** *New method added*

I know this is a very old question. However, I can't resist the temptation to post a new *very interesting* method to solve this old problem:

```dos
@echo off 

set MYSTRING=USER=Andy,IP=1.2.3.4,HOSTNAME=foobar,PORT=1234

set "%MYSTRING:,=" & set "%"

echo USER=%USER%, IP=%IP%, HOSTNAME=%HOSTNAME%, PORT=%PORT%
```

If you want to know where the magic is, remove the `@echo off` line, execute the program and carefully review the screen...

Answer (score 1):

In case your input is something like HOSTNAME:PORT and you need to split into separate variables then you can use this

```
@echo off
set SERVER_HOST_PORT=10.0.2.15:8080


set SERVER_HOST_PORT=%SERVER_HOST_PORT::=,%

for /F "tokens=1* delims=," %%a in ("%SERVER_HOST_PORT%") do (
   set SERVER_HOST=%%a
   set SERVER_PORT=%%b
)

echo SERVER_HOST=%SERVER_HOST%
echo SERVER_PORT=%SERVER_PORT%
```