# %Computername% Up to a certain character for naming files

Tags: batch-file, split

So we are running a backup script for my job and until now they just had the script pull the computer name and use that as the folder it creates.  The problem that we are encountering is that when we go to then use the restore script it becomes useless.

Our computer names are for example SMITHT#-Year-A.

But I would like the batch script to not use the whole name because often this is used when we change the year of the computer.  And because sometimes there are numbers after a persons name there are variying lengths so most of the knowledge I have on deciding start and stop points is coming up useless.

Is there a way to have the batch create a folder using the %COMPUTERNAME% function telling it to stop at the "-" so all we get is the name and number of the person?

Comment: take a look at `for /F "delims=- eol=-" %L in ("%COMPUTERNAME%") do (echo %L)` (see `for /?` for details...); when using this line in a batch file, replace `%L` by `%%L`...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820913/windows-batch-file-splitting-a-string-to-set-variables

Comment: Thank you!  That looks like it should work!

Answer (score 1):

To split a string at a certain character use `for /F`:

```
for /F "tokens=1 delims=- eol=-" %L in ("%COMPUTERNAME%") do (set SHORTNAME=%L)
```

This command line stores the string portion before the (first) `-` into variable `SHORTNAME`.

For details type `for /?` in the console window.

To use the above line in a batch script, replace `%L` by `%%L`.