# Find if parameter contains a comma separator, if it does, split it

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to process several parameters in a batch file. It might be a simple parameter or a composite one with an argument and related path.

Format for a composite parameter should be something like: `""ARG=CUSTOM_SOURCE,SOURCE=C:\Folder\OtherFolder\SourceFiles""`

I can't figure out how to get and set values for ARG and SOURCE.

What I've got so far:

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion     

set sep=","
set str1=%3

if not "x!str1:%sep%=!"=="x%str1%" (
    echo found pattern   rem gets here with no problem
    echo 3 is %3   rem output: string is "ARG=CUSTOM_SOURCE,SOURCE=C:\Folder\OtherFolder\SourceFiles"
    set sourceString=%3 
    echo "%sourceString%" rem output: ""

    REM extract source path from argument
    :nextVar
    for /F "tokens=1* delims=," %%a in ("%3") do (                     
        set %%a
        echo "%%a" REM output: "ARG CUSTOM_SOURCE SOURCE C:\Folder\OtherFolder\SourceFiles"
        set sourceString=%%b 
        echo "%%b" "sourceString" REM output: "" ""         
    )
    if defined sourceString goto nextVar
    echo "%ARGS%" "%SOURCE%" REM output: "" "" 
)
```

Code for splitting source string I got from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18821153/6385702.

Tried other option too but nothing works so far. Seems, the main problem I have with `set var=string` part. Even with `enabledelayedexpansion` I get empty values.

I'm not fluent with batch files and got really stacked with this one. What am I missing here?

**EDIT:**
parameters are passed from hta application (and also can be passed from command prompt directly)
format is following: `cmd /k myBatch.cmd PARAM REQ_PARAM "ARG=CUSTOM_SOURCE,SOURCE=C:\Folder\OtherFolder\SourceFiles" OPTIONAL_PARAM`

Comment: Okay, so now, `"ARG=CUSTOM_SOURCE,SOURCE=C:\Folder\OtherFolder\SourceFiles"` is the third argument out of four and is surrounded in only one set of doublequotes instead of two! And surely your HTML Application can pass the parameters already split at the comma!

Comment: number of parameters isn't the issue here, in my example I've set it as %1, because there was no other. But I see the issue with sets of double quotes now.

Comment: Well that depends how you define "issue" because your code is clearly working with the first argument, `%1` which is expected to resolve as `PARAM`. If your question does not make sense or you do not edit it carefully, it will confuse readers and hinder potential solutions. And why can your HTML Application not pass the parameters already split at the comma?

Comment: I didn't edit it correctly. The cmd is used not only through GUI (HTML Applicaiton) but also directly. The tech task was to process the parameter in this way, so the path would be associated with the parameter. There are two required parameters and several optional parameters that are processed using SHIFT , which means I also have to build parameter processing so that the order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for failing was the double doublequotes in the passed parameter. After removing them, the arguments are processed correctly:

```
set test=%3
echo "%test%" rem output: ""ARG=CUSTOM_SOURCE,SOURCE=C:\Folder\OtherFolder\SourceFiles""

set test=%test:"=%
echo "%test%" rem output: "ARG=CUSTOM_SOURCE,SOURCE=C:\Folder\OtherFolder\SourceFiles"

:nextVar
   for /F "tokens=1* delims=," %%a in ("%test%") do (
      set %%a
      set test=%%b
   )
if defined test goto nextVar
echo ARG=%ARG%, SOURCE=%SOURCE%
rem output: ARG=CUSTOM_SOURCE, SOURCE=C:\Folder\OtherFolder\SourceFiles
```